loss wifi connection intermittently
sorry for my english if I make mistake.
I have installed Elementary os 7 in a dual Boot with Windows, since one year without problems, but since August, I've had always wifi connection loss

But in network parameters I'm connected

When I start with Windows or Linux version 6.5.0.41, I don't have problem.
Being with linux 6.5.0.41 or 6.8.0.40 my network parameters are the same


If you have some ideas, I will enjoy to read it, because I would like to continue to use it.
for information, my laptop is an Asus N550j with uefi boot and the network card is a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG.
Thank you
